# calling two assert functions inside simpletest testcase

Tags: phpunit

I have a function in my model(codeigniter framework) which sets two values in cookies.

I need to write unit test for the same.So in this case i need to call two assertEqual() function inorder to ensure that both cookies are set.

Does any one have idea of calling two assert function inside same testcase?

Comment: You can use as many assert functions in each test case as you wish, and it is very common to use 2+ in a single test case. But I think you might be asking something more complex? Can you explain your problem/question in more detail, or use a (small) code sample to demonstrate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// For example
public function testMyTest()
{
    $foo = 'test';
    $this->assertTrue(is_string($foo));
    $this->assertEquals('test', $foo);
    $this->assertEquals(4, strlen($foo));
}
```

see docs:: http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html